# add or remove a string from an array based on a checkbox

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, chakra-ui

i have a nextjs (using typescript) front end. I am attempting to create a user creation form where an administrator can create additional users. the goal is for the form to generate a simple user state object that will then be passed into a create user document function. The user object is incredibly simple. below:

```
const user = {
  name: "",
  email: "",
  roles: []

}
```

the roles are what is giving me a headache. I am attempting to use Chakra UI checkboxes to add or remove strings from the roles array

```
<CheckboxGroup colorScheme="green">
                <Stack spacing={[1, 5]} direction={["column", "row"]}>
                  <Text>roles</Text>
                  <Checkbox
                    value="admin"
                    id="admin"
                    name="admin"
                    onChange={handleCheckBoxChange}
                  >
                    admin
                  </Checkbox>
                  <Checkbox
                    value="user"
                    id="user"
                    name="user"
                    onChange={handleCheckBoxChange}
                  >
                    user
                  </Checkbox>
                </Stack>
              </CheckboxGroup>
```

I've managed to get the checkbox to toggle to assign a boolean to the the name of each checkbox, but that obviously doesn't do me much good.

here is my handleCheckBoxChange function

```
  const handleCheckBoxChange = (e: any) => {
    const target = e.target;
    const value = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    setRoles({ [name]: value });
    console.log(roles);
  };
```

literally all i want is for when the admin box is checked for the string 'admin' to be added to the roles away. when it's unchecked i want it removed. same for the user box.

likely this is an easy fix and i've just been staring at it too long

lmk

---

added pictures

[no roles checked - nothing in the array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfUza.png)

[admin checked, nothing in the array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VnYH.png)

[admin and user checked, array shows 'admin'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDSom.png)

[user checked, array shows 'user'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cw2Q8.png)

[both checked, array shows 'admin'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3gdn.png)

---

heres my entire code block - i am rendering this form inside a chakra ui popup modal

```
import {
  Button,
  Checkbox,
  CheckboxGroup,
  Input,
  Modal,
  ModalBody,
  ModalCloseButton,
  ModalContent,
  ModalFooter,
  ModalHeader,
  ModalOverlay,
  Stack,
  Text,
  useDisclosure,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { addUser } from "../../lib/firebase";

export default function AddUser() {
  const initialRef = React.useRef(null);
  const finalRef = React.useRef(null);
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();

  const router = useRouter();
  const customer = router.query.customer;
  const [roles, setRoles] = useState<string[]>([]);

  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  const handleInputChange = (e: any) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setUser({ ...user, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleCheckBoxChange = (e: any) => {
    const target = e.target;
    const name = target.name;
    setRoles((currentRoles) =>
      target.checked
        ? [...currentRoles, name]
        : currentRoles.filter((role) => role != name)
    );
    setUser({ ...user, roles: roles });
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    addUser(customer, user);
    onClose();
  };

  console.log(user);

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={onOpen}>add user</Button>

      <Modal
        isOpen={isOpen}
        onClose={() => {
          onClose();
          setUser([]);
        }}
        initialFocusRef={initialRef}
        finalFocusRef={finalRef}
      >
        <ModalOverlay />
        <ModalContent>
          <ModalHeader>Modal Title</ModalHeader>
          <ModalCloseButton />
          <ModalBody>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <Input
                ref={initialRef}
                name="name"
                placeholder="name"
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              />
              <Input
                name="email"
                placeholder="email"
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              />
              <CheckboxGroup colorScheme="green">
                <Stack spacing={[1, 5]} direction={["column", "row"]}>
                  <Text>roles</Text>
                  <Checkbox
                    name="admin"
                    value="admin"
                    onChange={handleCheckBoxChange}
                  >
                    admin
                  </Checkbox>
                  <Checkbox
                    name="user"
                    value="user"
                    onChange={handleCheckBoxChange}
                  >
                    user
                  </Checkbox>
                </Stack>
              </CheckboxGroup>
            </form>
          </ModalBody>

          <ModalFooter>
            <Button
              colorScheme="blue"
              mr={3}
              type="submit"
              onClick={handleSubmit}
            >
              submit
            </Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </ModalContent>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to just update the state based on the name like you are, but passing a function to the state setter that handles adding/removing the item, i.e.:

```
const handleCheckBoxChange = (e: any) => {
  const target = e.target;
  const name = target.name;
  setRoles((currentRoles) =>
    target.checked
      ? [...currentRoles, name]
      : currentRoles.filter((role) => role !== name)
  );
};
```

When passing a function to a state setter, the function will be passed the existing state and is expected to return the updated state. In this way, you will get the currently selected roles and either return a copy of it with the selected item added, or removed depending on if the checkbox is checked.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions.. i threw that code in and its adding and removing the strings from the array, but its removing when it's checked and adding when it's unchecked + some other weird things.. i'll add some pictures to my main post

Comment: Can you share your code that you are using to evaluate the current state? Here is a simple codesandbox of this working as expected: https://codesandbox.io/s/checkboxes-to-array-state-67rzvo?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: just updated post with entire piece of code

Comment: There is an additional issue in your code - setting state is not synchronous so calling `setUser` right after `setRoles` will not have the updated state for `roles`. With your current code the `roles` state will get the correct updated array but the `roles` field in `user` state will get the previous version. You'll either have to create the updated roles array outside of the roles `setState` function and pass it to both or you could use a `useEffect` to update your `user` state when the `roles` state changes.